# ImportDll в управляемом коде

Tags: c#, c++

Ситуация следующая: имеется сторонняя сишная либа, для которой в проекте есть обертка на плюсах (далее враппер) с некоторым функционалом. Из данного враппера в управляемом коде импортятся методы и вызываются. Все жило отлично (на платформе х86) до тех пор, пока поставщики либы не выпустили новую версию под х64. Соответственно возникла потребность перевести все это дело под платформу х64, для чего я обновил во враппере заголовочный файл и библиотеку (*.lib), которые поставляются вместе с сторонней либой и собственно ламу ДЛЛ-ку. Пересобрал все под х64 и начались проблемы, а именно: во враппере есть некая функция вида:

```
int Func(int);
```

импорт происходит успешно, но при передаче ей из с# кода целочисленного значения, например 10, в нее приходит какой-то "мусор" (совсем другое большое значение). В чем может быть проблема и какое лекарство? Импорт выглядит следующим банальным образом:

```
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Func(int width);
```

До перехода на другую платформу все работало и код враппера я не менял. Гугл молчит по поводу подобных проблем, поэтому подозреваю, что проблема в каких-то настройках проекта или еще чего-то - не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

**UP**: возможно я не до конца понятно описал проблему: она находится, как я понимаю именно во враппере, до вызова функций из сторонней либы я даже не дохожу в дебаге, так как я сразу вижу в параметрах функции враппера при вызове ее некорретное интовое значение и я не могу понять почему в него приходит мусор. Я создал рядом тестовый проект на плюсах, добавил подобную функцию и в дебаге в него из с# приходит ожидаемое значение. Пересмотрел 100 раз все настройки - все совпадает. Единственная разница - это способ експорта функций, но так как я в этом не оч понимаю, то для меня сложно сделать какие либо выводы. Во враппере прошлые разработчики делают следующее:

```
#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

#pragma once

namespace NeoFaceWrapperNamespace
{
   //classes with functions
}
```

В тестовом проекте, в котором значения передаются корректно:

```
#ifdef MYWRAPPER_EXPORTS
#define MYWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the MyWrapper.dll
class MYWRAPPER_API CMyWrapper {
public:
    CMyWrapper(void);
    // TODO: add your methods here.
};

extern MYWRAPPER_API int nMyWrapper;

MYWRAPPER_API int fnMyWrapper(int);
```

И соответственно реализация функций в тестовом немного иначе выглядит. Тестовый - это проект, который студия создает по умолчанию, я единственно изменил платформу в нем на х64 и поменял параметры функции под мои случай.

**ПС: тому, кто поможет разобраться с проблемой пожертвую 100 очков репутации =)**

Comment: А код на C# при вызове этой функции как выглядит?

Comment: @wind, это наверное лучше спрашивать у тех, кто писал эту библиотеку. Имеет смысл поискать их сайт/форум и там спросить. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Возможности нет и эта стороння длл тут абсолютно не причем, так как до нее даже дело не доходит.

Comment: Код выглядит банально: int res = SomeClass.Func(10);

Comment: Посмотри здесь http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/ezakhareyev/2271/
Может поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решает проблему объявление функций с модификатором *static* или вынесение функций из класса (именно по этому в тестовом проекте не было проблем). Не знаю с чем это связано, но вот так...

Comment: Не знаю, причем тут static, но плюсую. Кстати, как ни странно, в англоязычной Википедии есть описание похожего случая: "Microsoft x64 calling convention: Parameters less than 64 bits long are not zero extended; the high bits contain garbage." Правда, не написано, с чем это связано и как обойти.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграть с **CallingConvention** - возможно, что кроме поддержки х64 заодно сменили и его. Чтобы выяснить точнее - нужно посмотреть в .h файл библиотеки, как там объявлена функция.

Comment: Пробывал все варианты - не помогает.

Comment: Я так понимаю нужно смотреть это? #define SOME_API __declspec(dllexport) или какая еще информация важна из заголовочного файла?

Comment: Как вообще понять какой конверсейшен нужно использовать? Где и как данная информация указывается? Я смотрю не в том месте, или по обновлению в вопросе можно сказать, что например во враппере надо стдкол, а в тестовом Cdecl ? В тестовом я пробовал оба варианта и в обоих случаях корректное значение, в реальном враппере всегда мусор...

Answer (score 0):

Не сильно вникал в вашу проблему, но может это поможет

> NEVER use "int" or "integer" as lParam. Your code WILL crash on 64-bit windows. ONLY use IntPtr, a "ref" structure, or an "out" structure.

[user32.SendMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) - раздел notes.

Comment: Сказано вроде как четко - никогда не юзайте, но почему тогда оно работает в тестовом проекте? И изменять все функции во враппере и в вызывающем коде не хотелось бы.